# Pyqt: Making a widget update without mouse focus

Tags: python, qt, events, widget, pyqt5

I'm making something akin to a screen recorder using the PyQT library. My problem is that the only way I can think to get the recording part of the application to run is in the "paint event" part of the widget class. Here's some code for example:

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
       #setup window

    def initUI(self):
       #init UI stuff

    def paintEvent(self, event):
       #capture the screen and then display it on this widget



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My main problem is on the paintevent area. I could start a thread and let the at capture and save frames, but I want to actively display each frame on the window. This can work while the widget has focus, but once the mouse moves away, and the window loses focus, then it stops because the paintevent is not being activated.

Is there anyway to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: Can't you just use a [`QTimer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) to trigger the required functionality?